# Weblogic 12c change domain name

Tags: dns, weblogic, rename

Does anyone know what is the correct way to change domain name in WLS 12c?

After changed domain name i have this error:

> `<2015-03-03 15:51:55 CET> <Critical> <JTA> <BEA-110482> <A logging last  resource (LLR) failed during initialization. The server cannot boot unless all configured LLRs initialize. Failing reason:`
>
> javax.transaction.SystemException: Failed to call > registerLoggingResourceTransactions() weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException: weblogic.transaction.loggingresource.LoggingResourceException: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC LLR, table verify failed for table >'CS_CMS.WL_LLR_MYSERVER', row 'JDBC LLR Domain//Server' record had unexpected value 'aaa//myserver' expected 'bbb//myserver'*** ONLY the original domain and server that creates an LLR table may access it ***

Could anyone tell how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a weblogic domain is not as simple as renaming a folder, check the following:

- Tons of files within your domain folder are going to reference the domain name, do a `grep -r your_domain *` and you will see where it's referenced. You can exclude tmp, cache, etc. like `--exclude-dir={tmp,logs,cache}`
- After looking at the above, you can do something like `xargs sed –I ‘s/your_domain/new_domain/g’` on all the files containing the old name
- Last, in regards to the error you're seeing, Weblogic keeps a LLR table with a single row that includes the path to the domain. Update that table with the new/path (see the Oracle link below)

See this [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/jta/llr.html) with regards to that table

See this [example](http://geekflare.com/how-to-rename-weblogic-domain-name/) on changing the domain name. Note this example does not include modifying the LLR table.